Use reflection to save/load data from/for many different objects
I am making a tile-based RPG in Java with a 3d array of tiles, each tile having an entity etc. I know how to save/load the tiles (grass has an id of 0, tiles[i][j][k] = Tile.getTile(0)), but entities and their inventory is much more complex, the health and inventory of each of these objects could be unique per entity:
public class Entity {

    //e.g poisoned, cursed
    public ArrayList<String> effects = new ArrayList<>();

    //e.g infernal, humanoid
    public ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Injury> injuries = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<Disease> diseases = new ArrayList<>();

    public String name;

    //AI
    public boolean hasAI = false;
    public Faction faction;

    //animation
    public DisplayChar disChar = new DisplayChar(null,null);

    public int row;
    public int col;

    //Stats
    public int maxHP;
    public int hp;
    public int dodge;
    public int armor;
    public int eyes = 2; //affects Perception stat, 0 eyes has penalties

    //Average speed is 100, higher numbers are slower, 0 is time stop. All speed is relative to the player. Speed comes from items and limbs.
    public int speed;
    public int turnPoints;

    public Inventory inventory;

Edit 1: Inventory and Item code
public class Inventory {
    public ArrayList<Item> items;
    //readme
    public int money;
}

public int temp;
    public int meltingPoint;
    public int freezingPoint;
    public double worth;
    public boolean stackable;
    public double weight;
    public int itemId;

    //visual
    public String name;
    public DisplayChar disChar = new DisplayChar(null,null);
    public Description description;


    //for when on a grid
    //set to -1 if in an inventory
    public int gridX = -1;
    public int gridY = -1;

How would I save and load all of these objects?
I expected there to be a premade process for this in Java, but that was just wishful thinking.

You could save these in many different ways.

Transform to JSON or XML and save it in a file => might get very large.
Transform using something like Protobuf files => much smaller, but no longer human readable.


You want serialization. Java has one built-in. There are others.

Java very much does have this built-in, it's just we've all collectively realized trying to generally solve serialization wasn't/isn't a good idea. Instead, use SQLite and do the hard work of creating tables for each persistent type and write the code to save/load. It's tedious, but you'll quickly be thankful you took that approach.
